# .onion connection is not secure

Tags: nginx, tor

I am trying to setup a .onion address to point to my https site. Everytime I try to access it from the .onion address I get a warning in Tor browser:

> Your connection is not secure. The owner of myonionaddress.onion has
>   configured their website improperly. To protect your information from
>   being stolen, Tor Browser has not connected to this website.

.

Other .onion sites (facebook's, duckduckgo's, etc.) load fine and don't have a warning...just mine. What am I doing wrong?

My config:

```
HiddenServiceDir /home/user/onion_folder
HiddenServiceVersion 3
HiddenServicePort 443 187.485.887.28:443
```

running version 0.3.4.9

EDIT:

My website has the following to redirect http to https:

```
if ($scheme != "https") {
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

How do I redirect regular users to the https version while allowing http from the .onion address?

EDIT 2:

I've also tried:

```
if ($scheme != "https") {
  if ($host !~* "\.onion$") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}
```

EDIT #3:

```
server {
  listen 80; server_name example.com www.example.com yourhiddenserviceaddress.onion;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to allow "insecure" (http) connections to your site from your hidden service.

The config should look like:

```
HiddenServiceDir /home/user/onion_folder
HiddenServiceVersion 3
HiddenServicePort 80 187.485.887.28:80
```

You will also need to make sure that the website doesn't attempt to redirect the visitor to `https` or your primary domain (instead of the .onion address).

Some certificate authorities <sup>(which ones?)</sup> may issue SSL certificates to `.onion` hosts but it is not necessary to enable secure connections.  Tor hidden service connections are encrypted from end-to-end so you don't need the SSL certificate to secure the connection, only to establish trust that the hidden service *is* actually operated by your company/site and is not a fake.

---

Bootnote:

At least one CA that will issue certificates to .onion domains is [DigiCert](https://www.digicert.com/blog/ordering-a-onion-certificate-from-digicert/).

Comment: I tried that with no luck. How do I "allow "insecure" (http) connections to your site from your hidden service" while redirecting regular users to the https version? I've updated my question with my nginx.conf.

Comment: I don't have an nginx setup to test with, but something along the lines of `if ($host !~* "\.onion$") {` immediately inside your scheme check.  That would say "if the scheme is not https AND the host TLD is not .onion" then redirect to https, otherwise leave it alone.  Running the hidden service and public site from the same host may require special care like this in both the application itself *and* the server config.  Your application must know to refer to the onion address rather than the normal host etc.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. Get an "Unable to connect" error in Tor browser.

Comment: See edit #2. $host wouldn't ever be .onion, no? The torrc is essentially a reverse proxy, right?

Comment: The .onion hostname will be passed through to nginx.  You will need to 1) make sure your nginx virtual host listens on port 80 (looks like it does) and 2) that it is configured to send requests to the onion address to the right virtual host.  Something like: `server { listen       80;  server_name  yourdomain.org  www.yourdomain.org yourhiddenserviceaddress.onion; ... }`

Comment: That doesn't work either ;(. I get a "Unable to connect error".

Comment: I'd start by troubleshooting locally.  From the server where you are running Tor, can you telnet to the Hidden Service Port and make a request (e.g. 187.485.887.28 443).  If so, use curl to debug if the nginx configuration is working: `curl -Lv --resolve "yourhiddenservice.onion:80:127.0.0.1" http://yourhiddenservice.onion/`  Replace 127.0.0.1 to the IP address where your web server listens on.  This will make a request to the onion address locally.

Comment: When I telnet using 443 port I get a 400 response. Using 80 port I get a redirect if I use the example.com or yourhiddenservice.onion.

Comment: That probably explains it.  You don't want to use 443 for the hidden service due to SSL certificate issues, but want to proxy to port 80.  Port 80 when testing with curl forcing the onion address to resolve locally **should not** redirect and instead serve the page over HTTP.

Comment: Much appreciated, thanks!  Did you end up getting it working completely? If so, would you mind sharing the relevant nginx config?  I've only set it up with Apache and would like to save the results for later.